# How to get the MSG value from inside my WindowProc?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, wndproc

Does the Win32 API provide any means to retrieve the [struct `MSG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958(v=vs.85).aspx) value that the [WindowProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx) is currently processing, from inside the proc?

P.S. I can't use notorious global constructs like static, it will surely bite me later on.
If it's relevant, the reason I need this is to pump the messages to other handlers (that I know of only at runtime) for the actual processing, and I don't want to lose any data as long as I can help it.

Comment: Why other handlers wait for `MSG` structure on input and not `(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)`?

Comment: @DmitriyZakablukov Because I want to keep the data in `MSG`'s `pt` and `time`.

Comment: well, you can write your own implementation of `DispatchMessage()` function, which will retrieve a pointer to the `WndProcFunction` from `HWND`, using `GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC)`, and which will subsequently call `CallWindowProc()`. After that you can decide, either pass `MSG` to other handlers or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first four members of the [MSG structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958.aspx) are passed to the window procedure. The remaining members can be retrieved through API calls. You can get the `pt` value using [GetMessagePos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938.aspx) and the `time` value using [GetMessageTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644939.aspx).